# ImplicitRegion with parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

My goal would be to run the following code:

```
{a, b} = {0.1, 3.5};
cons = (d > 0 && -d < c < b + d);

reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && 0 < z < b && z < c + d y, {x, y, z}];
u[c_, d_] := Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ reg, Assumptions -> cons]
v[c_, d_] := Integrate[y, {x, y, z} ∈ reg, Assumptions -> cons]
w[c_, d_] := Integrate[z, {x, y, z} ∈ reg, Assumptions -> cons]

f[c_, d_] := v[c, d]/(π a b + u[c, d])
g[c_, d_] := (π a b^2 + 2 w[c, d])/(2 (π a b + u[c, d]))

m[c_, d_] := (π^2 a b^2 + u[c, d]^2)/(2 π (π a b + u[c, d]))
n[c_, d_] := (1 - f[c, d]) Sqrt[1 + d^2]/d

NMaximize[{n[c, d] - m[c, d], cons && d == (1 - f[c, d])/g[c, d]}, {c, d}]
```

but unfortunately I'm not getting any output.

Would you know how to improve it and get the following result?

> {0.40194, {c->1.04187, d->0.920991}}

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Nintegrate` in the definitions of `u,v,w`

```
{a, b} = {1/10, 7/2}
```

You should split your region `reg` into a part concerning `x,y` and a part concerning `z`: `0<z , Min[b, c + d y]`.

```
kreis = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, y}]

u[c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[1, {x, y } \[Element] kreis , {z, 0,Min[b, c + d y]}]
v[c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[y, {x, y } \[Element] kreis , {z, 0, Min[b, c + d y]}]
w[c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[z, {x, y } \[Element] kreis , {z, 0,Min[b, c + d y]}]
```

your definitions `f,g,m,n` (unchanged)

```
f[c_, d_] := v[c, d]/(\[Pi] a b + u[c, d])
g[c_, d_] := (\[Pi] a b^2 + 2 w[c, d])/(2 (\[Pi] a b + u[c, d]))

m[c_, d_] := (\[Pi]^2 a b^2 +u[c, d]^2)/(2 \[Pi] (\[Pi] a b + u[c, d]))
n[c_, d_] := (1 - f[c, d]) Sqrt[1 + d^2]/d
```

Maximization takes some time

```
NMaximize[{n[c, d] - m[c, d], d > 0, d > c - b, d > -c,d == (1 - f[c, d])/g[c, d]}, {c, d} ]  
(*{0.40194, {c -> 1.0419, d -> 0.920991}*)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Constraint `d == (1 - f[c, d])/g[c, d]` is very time consuming